# How to make my Python plugin for text-editors execute every time a word is found in file?

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I've created a simple plugin for my school project. it kind of looks for bootstrap class names (`col-1`, `container` etc) and automatically writes the CSS style commands behind those class names inside your `style.css` file.

> so the idea is that you don't actually need bootstrap's link in the
>   header and your `style.css` file isn't full of unnecessary CSS
>   commands as *all the Bootstrap components are already in your text editor*.

ex:
`<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">Regular shadow</div>`

Because the div above has `shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded` as its Bootstrap class names, my plugin will write those five CSS stylings inside the `style.css` file.

With that being clear, I wanted to ask.. how to actually make the script work?? I mean I have the code, it works just fine when I run it in the terminal **BUT** **how can I set the plugin in my text editor and make it run every time it finds a keyword in the HTML file?**

piece of code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
keyword = {
"row": '''
    .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; 
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    }'''
    #etc
        }   

with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
   with open('style.css', 'a') as newfile:
      lines = file.readlines()
      for line in lines:
         if 'class="' in line:
            to_replace = line.split('"')[1].split()
            to_replace = OrderedDict.fromkeys(to_replace)
            for key in to_replace:
                if key in keyword:
                    newfile.write(keyword[key])
                    keyword[key] = ''
```

the HTML file:

```
<div class="row"></div> etc
```

output in `style.css`:

```
.row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex; 
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        }
```

also, are there any holes (i'm sure there are) in this script? Could you please point them out?

Comment: can you please add more details? including code, example, expected output etc.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori updated the question! could you please check out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to update in real-time as you type, the answer has less to do with Python and more about writing a custom plugin for your specific text editor.

However, if you're satisfied with it only running every time you save, you can get that functionality fairly simply using something like the [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) module. The [on_modified](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler.on_modified) event handler is probably what you're after.

Comment: great! Could you be so kind to demonstrate how to use it in my case? i couldn't figure how it works..